# xcodeのViewでwidthとheightを変えてもサイズが変わらない

Tags: xcode

赤いViewをHeight50,Weight50にしたいのですが、AutoLayoutのAdd New Constraintsから変更しても大きさが変わらないんです。
どうしたらいいでしょうか？

[image]
[image]

Comment: AutoLayoutは、制約（Constraint）をセットするものであり、widthやheightの値を変えても、Storyboard上のビューのサイズは変化しません。（シミュレータでプロジェクトを起動すると、制約に従った値で、ビューのサイズが表示されるはずでは、あります）Storyboardの標準的な使い方としては、まずStoryboard上でビュー等の位置やサイズをドラッグするなどして決定し、その後、AutoLayoutで制約をセットすると、無駄な手間が省けます。（質問がざっくりすぎて、回答の体裁のある内容になりそうにないので、コメントでの反応（Reply）としました。もうすこし具体的な内容を入れた質問に編集していただけたら、回答もしやすくなると思います）

Comment: -nagonsoftware様　コメントありがとうございます。初心者なものでどう説明していいかもわからず、申し訳ありません。なるべく詳細に書き直して写真も追加しましたのでお目通しいただければ幸いです。

Comment: @沢井海さん。もうしわけありません。もうすこしわかりやすい表現をするべきでしたが、私が求めているのは、質問者さんが何をしたいのか、何を求めているのかです。Storyboardでボタン、ラベル、ビューなどのパーツをレイアウトしたいのでしょうか（つまりAutoLayout機能に関心はない）、それともAutoLayoutのなんたるかを勉強し、使えるようになりたいのでしょうか？前者なら、AutoLayoutの説明はしませんし、後者なら、その概念と、UIKitに導入されたいきさつから回答を始めます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらく、そのビューの縦横の位置も指定すると、自動的に指定のサイズ(と位置)に表示されると思います。
Storyboardは、ビューの位置とサイズの全部が確定できるまで、自動的に設定を反映してくれません。矛盾する設定を複数セットしたりしても同じようになります。

AutoLayoutの設定上のエラーは、画面キャプチャにあるツリー表示の一番上の項目の"View Controller Scene"の右側にある、赤い丸内に→があるアイコンをクリックすると一応表示されます。

開発頑張ってください。